# How To: use AngularJS to recursively loop through lists and sub lists, looking for data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote this incredibly awful super-nested loop tonight, and I just know that there must be a substantially better way to do it. So, the basics:

- `orgId` = a `Guid` (potentially without dashes, because sometimes my angular likes to drop them)
- `rootOrgList` = a list of **Id** (`Guid`), and **Name** (`String`), and **ParentOrgId** (`Guid`)

The goal: look in the `rootOrgList` for any instance of the `orgId`, and get the `parentOrgId` for that `orgId`.

Now, this loop works, and since it's all for loops, it's actually pretty dang fast, but it's WAY too long, WAY too nested, and WAY too stupid of a way to do it, but I'm tired, and annoyed, and can't look at it any more without wanting to bang my head on my desk.

So, does anyone have ideas to achieve the desired result, in a better fashion? (The loops below, btw, will give you a pretty good idea of the structure of the data, which is why I haven't supplied a JSON of it.)

```
vm.getParentOrgId = (
  function(orgId, rootOrgList) {
    var parentOrgId = "";
    var curParentOrgId = orgId;

    //#region Check the Root Level list
    var idxLvlRoot = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(rootOrgList, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
    if (idxLvlRoot > -1) {
      //Found it? Great! We're done. Return the org we came in with!
      return guidifyString(orgId);
    }
    //#endregion

    //#region If it's not in the root level, check for sub-lists
    for (var orgRoot = 0; orgRoot < rootOrgList.length; orgRoot++) {
      curParentOrgId = rootOrgList[orgRoot].Id;

      if (hasValue(rootOrgList[orgRoot].Organizations)) {
        var orgSubListLvl1 = rootOrgList[orgRoot].Organizations;

        //#region Check the Sub list for it
        var idxSubLvl1 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl1, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
        if (idxSubLvl1 > -1) {
          //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
          return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
        }
        //#endregion

        //#region Not there? Look deeper, if you can
        for (var orgSubLvl1 = 0; orgSubLvl1 < orgSubListLvl1.length; orgSubLvl1++) {
          curParentOrgId = orgSubListLvl1[orgSubLvl1].Id;

          if (hasValue(orgSubListLvl1[orgSubLvl1].Organizations)) {
            var orgSubListLvl2 = orgSubListLvl1[orgSubLvl1].Organizations;

            //#region Check the Sub list for it
            var idxSubLvl2 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl2, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
            if (idxSubLvl2 > -1) {
              //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
              return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
            }
            //#endregion

            //#region Not there? Look deeper, if you can
            for (var orgSubLvl2 = 0; orgSubLvl2 < orgSubListLvl2.length; orgSubLvl2++) {
              curParentOrgId = orgSubListLvl2[orgSubLvl2].Id;

              if (hasValue(orgSubListLvl2[orgSubLvl2].Organizations)) {
                var orgSubListLvl3 = orgSubListLvl2[orgSubLvl2].Organizations;

                //#region Check the Sub list for it
                var idxSubLvl3 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl3, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
                if (idxSubLvl3 > -1) {
                  //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
                  return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
                }
                //#endregion

                //#region Not there? Look deeper, if you can
                for (var orgSubLvl3 = 0; orgSubLvl3 < orgSubListLvl3.length; orgSubLvl3++) {
                  curParentOrgId = orgSubListLvl3[orgSubLvl3].Id;

                  if (hasValue(orgSubListLvl3[orgSubLvl3].Organizations)) {
                    var orgSubListLvl4 = orgSubListLvl3[orgSubLvl3].Organizations;

                    //#region Check the Sub list for it
                    var idxSubLvl4 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl4, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
                    if (idxSubLvl4 > -1) {
                      //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
                      return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
                    }
                    //#endregion

                    //#region Not there? Look deeper, if you can
                    for (var orgSubLvl4 = 0; orgSubLvl4 < orgSubListLvl4.length; orgSubLvl4++) {
                      curParentOrgId = orgSubListLvl4[orgSubLvl4].Id;

                      if (hasValue(orgSubListLvl4[orgSubLvl4].Organizations)) {
                        var orgSubListLvl5 = orgSubListLvl4[orgSubLvl4].Organizations;

                        //#region Check the Sub list for it
                        var idxSubLvl5 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl5, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
                        if (idxSubLvl5 > -1) {
                          //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
                          return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
                        }
                        //#endregion

                        //#region Not there? Look deeper, if you can
                        for (var orgSubLvl5 = 0; orgSubLvl5 < orgSubListLvl5.length; orgSubLvl5++) {
                          curParentOrgId = orgSubListLvl5[orgSubLvl5].Id;

                          if (hasValue(orgSubListLvl5[orgSubLvl5].Organizations)) {
                            var orgSubListLvl6 = orgSubListLvl5[orgSubLvl5].Organizations;

                            //#region Check the Sub list for it
                            var idxSubLvl6 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl6, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
                            if (idxSubLvl6 > -1) {
                              //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
                              return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
                            }
                            //#endregion

                            //#region Not there? Look deeper, if you can
                            for (var orgSubLvl6 = 0; orgSubLvl6 < orgSubListLvl6.length; orgSubLvl6++) {
                              curParentOrgId = orgSubListLvl6[orgSubLvl6].Id;

                              if (hasValue(orgSubListLvl6[orgSubLvl6].Organizations)) {
                                var orgSubListLvl7 = orgSubListLvl6[orgSubLvl6].Organizations;

                                //#region Check the Sub list for it
                                var idxSubLvl7 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl7, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
                                if (idxSubLvl7 > -1) {
                                  //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
                                  return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
                                }
                                //#endregion

                                //#region Not there? Look deeper, if you can
                                for (var orgSubLvl7 = 0; orgSubLvl7 < orgSubListLvl7.length; orgSubLvl7++) {
                                  curParentOrgId = orgSubListLvl7[orgSubLvl7].Id;

                                  if (hasValue(orgSubListLvl7[orgSubLvl7].Organizations)) {
                                    var orgSubListLvl8 = orgSubListLvl7[orgSubLvl7].Organizations;

                                    //#region Check the Sub list for it
                                    var idxSubLvl8 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl8, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
                                    if (idxSubLvl8 > -1) {
                                      //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
                                      return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
                                    }
                                    //#endregion

                                    //#region Not there? Look deeper, if you can
                                    for (var orgSubLvl8 = 0; orgSubLvl8 < orgSubListLvl8.length; orgSubLvl8++) {
                                      curParentOrgId = orgSubListLvl8[orgSubLvl8].Id;

                                      if (hasValue(orgSubListLvl8[orgSubLvl8].Organizations)) {
                                        var orgSubListLvl9 = orgSubListLvl8[orgSubLvl8].Organizations;

                                        //#region Check the Sub list for it
                                        var idxSubLvl9 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl9, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
                                        if (idxSubLvl9 > -1) {
                                          //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
                                          return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
                                        }
                                        //#endregion

                                        //#region Not there? Look deeper, if you can
                                        for (var orgSubLvl9 = 0; orgSubLvl9 < orgSubListLvl9.length; orgSubLvl9++) {
                                          curParentOrgId = orgSubListLvl9[orgSubLvl9].Id;

                                          if (hasValue(orgSubListLvl9[orgSubLvl9].Organizations)) {
                                            var orgSubListLvl10 = orgSubListLvl9[orgSubLvl9].Organizations;

                                            //#region Check the Sub list for it
                                            var idxSubLvl10 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(orgSubListLvl10, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
                                            if (idxSubLvl10 > -1) {
                                              //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
                                              return guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
                                            }
                                            //#endregion

                                            //At this point, if we still haven't found it, we aren't going to.
                                          }
                                        }
                                        //#endregion
                                      }
                                    }
                                    //#endregion
                                  }
                                }
                                //#endregion
                              }
                            }
                            //#endregion
                          }
                        }
                        //#endregion
                      }
                    }
                    //#endregion
                  }
                }
                //#endregion
              }
            }
            //#endregion
          }
        }
        //#endregion
      }
    }
    //#endregion

    return parentOrgId;
  }
);
```

**Update**
After looking at the answer from @adolfotcar, I modified my code to introduce recursion to fix the problems. Below is the result:

```
vm.getParentOrgId = (
  function(orgId, rootOrgList) {
    var parentOrgId = "";
    var curParentOrgId = orgId;

    //#region Check the Root Level list
    var idxLvlRoot = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(rootOrgList, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
    if (idxLvlRoot > -1) {
      //Found it? Great! We're done. Return the org we came in with!
      return guidifyString(orgId);
    }
    //#endregion

    //#region If it's not in the root level, check for sub-lists
    for (var orgRoot = 0; orgRoot < rootOrgList.length; orgRoot++) {
      if (hasValue(rootOrgList[orgRoot].Organizations)) {
        curParentOrgId = rootOrgList[orgRoot].Id;

        //#region Check the Sub list for it
        var idxSubLvl1 = indexOfDashlessStringInArray(rootOrgList[orgRoot].Organizations, guidifyString(orgId), "Id");
        if (idxSubLvl1 > -1) {
          //Found it? Great! We're done. Return it!
          parentOrgId = guidifyString(curParentOrgId);
          return parentOrgId;
        }
        //#endregion

        //If we still haven't found it, recurse the method call to go deeper.
        parentOrgId = vm.getParentOrgId(orgId, rootOrgList[orgRoot].Organizations);
      }
    }
    //#endregion

    return parentOrgId;
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what rootOrgList looks like?

Comment: @adolfotcar - Added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's say your rootOrgList is something like:

```
$scope.list = [ 
                {id: 1, name: "a", parentId: 0, 
                    organizations: [
                                        {id: 2, name: "b", parentId: 1, organizations: [{id: 7, name: "g", parentId: 2, organizations: {}}]},
                                        {id: 3, name: "c", parentId: 1, organizations: []},
                                        {id: 4, name: "d", parentId: 1, 
                                            organizations: [
                                                                {id: 5, name: "e", parentId: 4, organizations: {}},
                                                                {id: 6, name: "f", parentId: 4, organizations: {}}
                                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                }
            ];
```

Then this function should do:

```
$scope.getParentId = function(haystack, needle){
    //it'll return 0 if not found
    var parentId = 0;
    angular.forEach(haystack, function(organization, key){
        if (organization.id==needle) {
            parentId = organization.parentId;
            return;// this return breaks only the foreach
        }
        //if parentId was found in the previous forEach then just keeps that value, if not then keeps looking in next sublevel
        parentId = parentId ? parentId : $scope.getParentId(organization.organizations, needle); 
    });
    return parentId;
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
var parentId = $scope.getParentId($scope.list, 4);
```

Obviously, you'll need to adjust the code to your variables names and other small bits, but it should do.

Comment: This was very close to doing what I needed, but in the end had some holes in it for the selection of the parent node. Your code was basically always setting the child as its own parent, but this put me on the right path for the recursion I needed to put in place.